# Can I pass ref with function component?

Tags: reactjs, function, dom, components

-I am using **function component**.
-for now I am using 3 components here, from that One is parent component and another 2 are child components. 
-I need to access one child component methods or state to another child methods. I already done with class components with **CreateRef** but for now I need to use with function components but I am getting Null inside 'ref.current'.

```js
export function SideBySideList(props) {
    const ref = React.createRef();

 //this is call inside ListPage after sucess
    function updateRightList(id) {
        ref.current.state.actualSearchedModel.Id = id
        ref.current.fetchDataAndUpdate();
    }
    function itemClicked(id) {
        updateRightList(id);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-12 no-padding">
                <div className={props.leftListLayoutClass}>
                    <ListPage
         updateRightList={updateRightList}
     />
                </div>
                <div className={props.rightListLayoutClass}>
                    <ListPage
                        ref={ref}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        <>
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you show the `ListPage` component code?

Answer (score 6):

According to the official documentation:

> You may not use the ref attribute on function components because they
>   don’t have instances

So if your `ListPage` is functional component, you have to convert it to the class component. Or your ref must refer to the DOM element inside of `ListPage`.

```
function ListPage ({ref}) {
  return <div ref={ref}>Hello!</div>
}
```

---

UPDATED:

```js
function ParentComponent () {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(null);
  
  const onChildMount = React.useCallback((dataFromChild) => {
    setState(dataFromChild);
  });
  
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
      <ChildComponent onMount={onChildMount} />
    </div>
  )
}

function ChildComponent (props) {
  const thisShouldBePassedToTheParent = "from child with love";
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.onMount(thisShouldBePassedToTheParent);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>child component</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ok got it. But is there any way to use one component's function to  another one after One is loaded?

Comment: Yep, I think you should use callback props and lifecycle methods to achieve this.

Comment: can you please explain in more details?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The snippet shows how to use callback props and lifecycle methods within functional components.

Comment: yes I used same kind of things, I used same kind of things and its working with setting object of function in parent state from child then call after change call from there.
Thank you for great response.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve, what you achieved in "UPDATED" part, but only when: Parent component is class component, and child component is functional component.

I have to resolve that, my parent component have some button Save, and when I click it, I want to fetch data from child. 
Previously when both child and parent components were class component I did it through ref. But I can't find way to do it when Parent is class and child is functional component (which use hooks for state)

Comment: I found solution to my question, and posted it on this page. I found it because of your solution @IvanBurnaev, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With functional components you can use refs like this:

```
// Import our hooks
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

// create our ref
const myInput = useRef();

// This is equivalent to our componentDidMount, this will focus
useEffect(() => myInput.current && myInput.current.focus());

// Parse our ref to our textField
<Textfield inputRef={myInput} />
```

Here you can read docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Also you may use refs like this directly:

```
<TextField inputRef={input => input && input.focus()} />
```

You can read full Article here: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-refs-both-class-and-functional-components-76b7bce487b8

Comment: As of React 16+, this is the correct answer to the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for solution where `Parent` is class component and `Child` is functional component, and want to get data from `child` (state, function)

**Class component:**

```
  class Parent extends React.Component {
     constructor(){
      this.setReferenceToElement = element => {
       this.fromChild = element;
      }
     }
     handleClick(){
       console.log(this.fromChild());
     }
    
     render(){
      return (
       <div>
         <Child setRef={this.setReferenceToElement} />
         <button onClick={handleClick}> Get state from child </button>
       </div>
      )
     }
    }
```

**Functional component:**

```
function Child(props){
 // ... it has some state 
 props.setRef(state => state);
 return <div> Test </div>
}
```